# Javascript, String formatting: I need the first 4 letters of a string, lowercase, whitespace skimmed, symbols removed

Tags: javascript, regex, string, formatting

...I should just list them:

1. First 4 letters/numbers, with...
2. All lowercase.
3. Whitespace stripped.
4. Symbols removed.

Should be simple.  What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Have you given the correct order of these operations? For example, if you have "A B C D", if you follow your rules you get "ab". Somehow I think you might want "abcd" though.

Comment: Ah, right.  Yeah I need the whitespace and symbols stripped before compressing to 4 characters.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. [`slice`](http://docs.sun.com/source/816-6408-10/string.htm#1194366)`(0, 4)`
2. [`toLowerCase`](http://docs.sun.com/source/816-6408-10/string.htm#1194765)`()`
3. [`replace`](http://docs.sun.com/source/816-6408-10/string.htm#1194258)`(/\s/g, '')`
4. `replace(/[^\w\s]/g, '')`

The third and fourth regexes can be combined more simply as just `\W`, to remove all non-alphanumerics, if that's what you want. If the ‘symbols’ you want to remove are more specific than that, you'll have to put them in a character class explicitly, eg. `/[!"#...]/g`. If you only mean that you want to remove whitespace at the start and end of a string (“trimming”):

```
replace(/^\s+/, '').replace(/\s+$/, '')
```

instead.(*)

Chain them together in whatever order is appropriate. If you want to chop to four characters *after* you've removed unwanted characters:

```
var processed= str.replace(/\W/g, '').toLowerCase().slice(0, 4);
```

(*: `string.trim()` is also available in ECMAScript Fifth Edition but not all browsers support it yet. You can hack `trim()` support into `String.prototype` if you would like to using `string.trim()` on all browsers today:)

```
if (!('trim' in String.prototype)) {
    String.prototype.trim= function() {
        return (''+this).replace(/^\s+/, '').replace(/\s+$/, '');
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
"  MY STRING  ".replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').substring(0,4).toLowerCase()
```

You can remove desired symbols with similar replace-method.

Answer (score 0):

> Whitespace stripped.

only from the ends, or the whole string? The following strips all whitespace (and anything other than numbers and letters - `\w` includes underscores too) from the string.

```
str = str.replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/ig).substring(0, 4).toLowerCase();
```